# Potential Dangers of Running Code in Parallel

Tags: c, bash, parallel-processing, race-condition

I am working in OSX and using bash for my shell. I have a script which calls an executable hundreds of times, and each call is independent of the other. Therefore I am going to run this code in parallel. However, each call to the executable appends output to a community text file on a new line.

The ordering of the text file is not of importance (although it would be nice, but totally not worth over complicating since I can just use unix sort command), but what is, is that every call of the executable properly printed to the file. My concern is that if I run the script in parallel that the by some freak accident, two threads will check out the text file, print to it and then save different copies back to the original directory of the text file. Thus nullifying one of the writes to the file.

Does this actually happen, or is my understanding of printing to a file flawed? I don't fully know if this would also be a case by case bases so I will provide some mock code of what is being done in my program below.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
abs=$1
input=$(echo "$abs" | awk '{print 0.004 + 0.005*$1 }')
./program input
```

"./program":

```
~~Normal .c file stuff here~~
~~VALUE magically calculated here~~
~~run number is pulled out of input and assigned to index for sorting~~

FILE *fpp;
fpp = fopen("Doc.txt","a");
fprintf(fpp,"%d, %.3f\n", index, VALUE);
fclose(fpp);

~Closing events of program.c~~
```

Commands to run script in parallel in bash:

```
printf "%s\n" {0..199} | xargs -P 8 -n 1 ./program
```

Thanks for any help you guys can offer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm helping here, but have you tried implementing Git?

Comment: Never tried, because I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that looks like a recipe for disaster. If those processes both hit opening the file at the roughly the same time, only one will "take".

I suggest either (easier) writing to separate files then catting them together when the processing is done, or (harder) sending all results to a consumer process that will write the file for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

A write() call (like fwrite()) with the append flag set in open() (like during fopen()) is guaranteed to avoid the race condition you describe.

O_APPEND
If set, the file offset shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write.

From: POSIX specifications for open:

[opengroup.org open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) are what you are thinking of.

Not 100% sure but if you simple append to the end of the file rather than opening it and editing it should be right

Comment: Okay, I did a run using append and it seemed to work, but I wasn't sure if I lucked out. Because it also worked when I used write to file, which I am fairly sure is prone to failure.

Comment: its possible that your script isn't running them in parallel but instead looping over it?

Comment: Well I think it's definitely parallel for a few reason. The output is ordered when gone through in a normal loop fashion, and in this case the output is not in order at all. The process is slow so I see the output appearing in chunks of 8, since there are 8 processes running at once. There are 256 steps which print out the the command line during the run of program, and the command line shows something like: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4... etc

Comment: yeah well if it works it works. Id be double checking that the output is what you want though, there is a definite possibility that your file gets overwritten rather than added to.

Comment: @NoviceC: As I said, you only get into trouble if two processes open the file at roughly the same time. It is improbable, but (I think) possible. Try putting a sizable `sleep` between `fopen` and `fprintf`, and see if your output is still okay.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option, make your program write to standard output instead of directly to a file. Then you can let the shell merge the output of your programs:

```
printf "%s\n" {0..199} | parallel -P 8 -n 1 ./program  > merged_output.txt
```

Comment: Could you clarify? I'm aware that this gives you no control over how the output from each of the instances of `program` is merged (i.e., you could get a few lines from one, then a line from another, more lines from the first, a few lines from the third, etc.) Given that the OP simply wanted to write a single line from each instance to the same file, it didn't seem to matter what order they appeared in. If `xargs` can mix two lines together ("one two" and "three four" becoming "one three fourwo", for instance), then yes, this is a problem.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't looked at the other answers. I thought there already was one that suggested `parallel`.

Comment: If you donot have GNU Parallel installed now, you can have it in 10 seconds: wget -O - pi.dk/3|bash